# Return Boost distribution generator from function to populate vectors in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector

I have the following function that should return a distribution generateor such that I can use the function to populate a vector i.e.

```
template<typename T3>
T3 new_func()
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> Uni(1,2);
    boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937, std::uniform_real_distribution<>> Uniform(gen , Uni);
    return Uniform;
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<double> test;
    //something like
    std::for_each(test.begin(), test.end(),
         [&](std::vector<double>& a){a.push_back(new_func());});
}
```

I specifically need this ability as I will have a single parameterized function to generate multiple distributions to be used in this fashion. Kindly suggest 
what exactly I need to do achieve this.

Comment: What is `T3`? And where is `gen` coming from? Is `new_func` supposed to receive that, along with the distribution parameters, as arguments? Please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I don't get why the question is downvoted. I assume people don't know what distributions are. Yes, the question wording is fumbling, but at least the pseudo code is pretty suggestive

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::function<>` (or even `std::function<>`):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10a401b0a33e4640)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/math/distributions.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <random>

static boost::mt19937 gen;
typedef boost::function<double()> Distri;

Distri new_func()
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> Uni(1,2);
    return boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937, std::uniform_real_distribution<>>(gen , Uni);
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<double> test;
    //something like
    Distri d = new_func();

    //likely
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(test), 100, d);
}
```